# Why will my data not plot to Canvas in qt4 with python? I have attached the code

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I am setting up a control system with live DAQ plotting. I have a GUI I've written in pyqt4 with 3 control buttons, a quit button and embedded matplotlib graph that i supposed to display live data. The data is printing to the terminal screen, but never plots into the GUI. If I close the UI, the figure will appear, but nothing is displayed. The plot function works alone as well, just have to use plt.ion() fig = plt.figgure() [both before ax is defined] ax = fig.add_subplot(111) and change self.draw() to fig.canvas.draw()

I've tried using different methods using pyqt4 and pyqt5. I think it is getting confused on what to display. I set up the main window for the GUI, and the three buttons, the work alone, but can't interact with them if the plot is included

```
'''
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as 
FigureCanvas
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import explorerhat
'''
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PiDAQ")

        ## Define Canvas size and location to be embedded into Main Window
        canvas = Canvas(self, width = 4, height = 4)
        canvas.move(200,20)

        self.show()

 ''' END CLASS'''

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width =5 , height = 5, dpi =100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.plot()
'''
     def plot(self):

        t0 = time.time()

        i=0
        print('t0=', t0)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        N=50

        x = np.arange(N)*20/N
        y1 = np.arange(N)*5/N
        y2 = np.arange(N)*5/N

        line1, = self.ax.plot(x, y1, 'b-')
        line2, = self.ax.plot(x, y2, 'r-')

        while True:
            i =+ 1
            V2 = self.explorerhat.analog.one.read()
            V3 = self.explorerhat.analog.two.read()
            V4 = self.explorerhat.analog.three.read()
            V5 = self.explorerhat.analog.four.read()
            if V2 > 2.5:
                output = ' POW!!! '
            else:
                output = ''
            t = time.time()-t0

            if i % N == 0:

                print(i, t, V2, V3, V4, V5, output)
            x[i%N-1] = t

            if i % N == 0:
                y1[-1] = V2
                y2[-1] = V3
                line1.set_xdata(x-x[0])
                line1.set_ydata(y1)
                line2.set_xdata(x-x[0])
                line2.set_ydata(y2)
                self.draw()
            else:
                y1[i%N-1] = V2
                y2[i%N-1] = V3
            time.sleep(0.00001)
 '''
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plot function never returns and so is blocking the event loop.

Qt works by having an infinite loop (the event loop) listen for events and then dispatching them to even handlers. Events can be keyboard presses, mouse clicks, repaint requests, TCP notifications, etc. Event handlers are the functions that do something with that event. They should return quickly because, as long as they are running, Qt can not process other events (Qt has only one thread that can handle GUI events). Event handlers that do not return make the application 'hang'. See [this artcicle](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Blocking_the_event_loop) for a more detailed explanation.

All your methods are called directly or indirectly because of some event occured (e.g. a button-click event handler emits the clicked signal which is connected to your slot). Therefor all the methods you write should return quickly (e.g. well within a second). Your `plot` function does not return and therefore the program hangs.

The solution would be to remove the while loop from your plot function and put the contents in a separate method that is called periodically by a QTimer. Something like this.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as 
FigureCanvas
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import explorerhat

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("PiDAQ")

        ## Define Canvas size and location to be embedded into Main Window
        canvas = Canvas(self, width = 4, height = 4)
        canvas.move(200,20)

        self.show()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(100) # 100 msec
        selt.timer.timeout.connect(canvas.updatePlot)



class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width =5 , height = 5, dpi =100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        self.t0 = time.time()

        self.i=0
        print('t0=', t0)
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        N=50

        self.x = np.arange(N)*20/N
        self.self.y1 = np.arange(N)*5/N
        self.y2 = np.arange(N)*5/N

        self.line1, = self.ax.plot(x, y1, 'b-')
        self.line2, = self.ax.plot(x, y2, 'r-')


    def updatePlot(self):
        self.i =+ 1
        V2 = self.explorerhat.analog.one.read()
        V3 = self.explorerhat.analog.two.read()
        V4 = self.explorerhat.analog.three.read()
        V5 = self.explorerhat.analog.four.read()
        if V2 > 2.5:
            output = ' POW!!! '
        else:
            output = ''
        t = time.time()-self.t0

        if self.i % N == 0:
            print(i, t, V2, V3, V4, V5, output)

        x = self.x
        x[i%N-1] = t

        if self.i % N == 0:
            self.y1[-1] = V2
            self.y2[-1] = V3
            self.line1.set_xdata(x-x[0])
            self.line1.set_ydata(y1)
            self.line2.set_xdata(x-x[0])
            self.line2.set_ydata(y2)
            self.draw()
        else:
            self.y1[i%N-1] = V2
            self.y2[i%N-1] = V3
```

Disclaimer, I did not run the code above. It may contain small bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's much appreciated. I ran the code after correcting a few things, it says Canvas is not defined, I checked for errors in spelling. I tried unindenting the Canvas class, which got rid of the error, but then says that fig = (figsize = (width, height), dpi= dpi), TypeError: "module" is not callable.

Comment: The entire `Canvas` class was indented to far, it should be at de same level as the `Window` class, just like in your code. I've edited my code above.